# <h:panelGroup layout="block"> does not render anything to HTML

Tags: jsf, html-rendering

I am trying to display some elements inside a `<h:panelGroup layout="block">`. The elements are being displayed on the screen, but the HTML `<div>` is not being rendered at all.

This is my JSF code:

```
<h:form id="editProfile">
    <div class="password-container">
        <h:outputText class="edit-header" value="Change Password &#8594;"></h:outputText>
        <br />
        <br />
        <!-- this div is not being displayed,
             THE ELEMENTS INSIDE THE PANELGROUP ARE BEING DISPLAYED -->
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <h:inputText a:placeholder="Present Password" id="password" 
                value="#{editProfile.password}"
                class="cff-inputText"></h:inputText>
            <br />
            <h:inputText a:placeholder="New Password" id="change-password"
                class="cff-inputText"></h:inputText>
            <br />
            <button id="cancel-password" class="cff-button">Cancel</button>
            <button id="ok-password" class="cff-button">OK</button>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

This is the generated HTML output:

```
 //This is not the panelGroup div
 <div class="password-container"><span class="edit-header">Change Password →</span>
                       <br /><br />

   //These are the elements inside the div! but the panelGroup Div is not being rendered
   <input id="editProfile:password" type="text" name="editProfile:password" class="cff-inputText" placeholder="Present Password" />
       <br /><input id="editProfile:change-password" type="text" name="editProfile:change-password" class="cff-inputText" placeholder="New Password" />
       <br />
       <button id="cancel-password" class="cff-button">Cancel</button>
       <button id="ok-password" class="cff-button">OK</button>

 </div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="6732837357534288958:1301728140408675513" autocomplete="off" />
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `id`, `style` or `styleClass` attribute, to be sure, that `<div>` will be rendered. Basically, it's adding something **if needed**.

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-jsp/h/panelGroup.html):

> Intended for use in situations when only one UIComponent child can be nested, such as in the case of facets.

In this case, you probably should use plain `<div>` instead of `h:panelGroup`.

Comment: I often use panelGroup to conditionally render a <div> based on the `rendered` condition. Alternatively, use `<ui:fragment>`